# Python: Use a for loop to get Nth number out of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get every 3rd value out of a list and add it to a new list.

This is what I have so far.

```
def make_reduced_samples(original_samples, skip):

    skipped_list = []

    for count in range(0, len(original_samples), skip):

        skipped_list.append(count)

    return skipped_list
```

`skip` is equal to 3

I get the indexes and not the value of the numbers in the list.

It gives me `[0,3,6]`. Which are the indexes in the list and not the value of the indexes.

The example I am given is:

In this list `[12,87,234,34,98,11,9,72]`, you should get `[12,34,9]`.

I cannot use `skipped_list = original_samples[::3]` in any way.

Comment: why can't you use slicing? That would be the way to go

Comment: It's unclear from your question why `[::3]` can't be used, since `[12,87,234,34,98,11,9,72][::3]` gives `[12, 34, 9]` as required. Could you please clarify the reasoning for this restriction?

Comment: Just for the purpose of the assignment I am not allowed to use it. I have to find another way through loops to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the value of the original_samples array at the index. Not the index (count) itself.

```
def make_reduced_samples(original_samples, skip):

    skipped_list = []

    for count in range(0, len(original_samples), skip):

        skipped_list.append(original_samples[count])

    return skipped_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct, most pythonic, and most efficient way to do that is to use slicing.

```
lst = [12, 87, 234, 34, 98, 11, 9, 72]

skipped_list = lst[::3]

print(skipped_list)  # [12, 34, 9]
```

If the step does not obey a linear relation (which it does here), then you could use a list-comprehension with `enumerate` to filter on the index.

```
skipped_list = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i % 3 == 0]

print(skipped_list)  # [12, 34, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

One liner:

```
skipped_list = [j for (i,j) in enumerate(original_samples, start=1) if i % 3 == 0]
```

Comment: starting at 1 in your enumerate returns the wrong answer.

Comment: If you need the 0 index then just omit the "start=1" argument. The question didn't state clearly when i posted this..

Comment: this does not omit the first element, it shifts all of them by one. Try it an compare it to the desired output

Comment: Right. It doesn't. My bad